# Como testar performance Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Pretendo criar mapeamento com herança
Pessoa -> Clientes, etc

Mas gostaria de testar performance com os 3 tipos de mapeamento( TPH,TPT,TPC)

Como faço ? ALguém teve experiencia para falar qual dos 3 se torna mais fácil e rápido ?

Comment: Quais 3 tipos de mapeamento?

Comment: São TPH,TPT,TPC

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o bom e velho Stop

```
public void Teste()
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var pessoas = MeuContexto.Pessoas.ToList();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Tempo demorado = {0}ms", sw.Elapsed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### TPH (Table per Hierarchy)

Todas as entidades da hierarquia serão mapeadas para uma única tabela.
Então, **não há necessidade de fazer *joins* para recuperar os dados, tendo geralmente uma melhor performance com relação a TPT.**

A desvantagem é a redundância de dados. Algumas colunas relacionadas a classes de entidades específicas podem conter valores nulos.

### TPT (Table per Type)

Cada entidade na hierarquia de classes é mapeada para uma tabela diferente. Então há necessidade de fazer *join* ao selecionar os dados, tendo geralmente uma performance inferior a TPH.

**Implemente caso necessário por questão de normalização e design (evita redundância). Com relação a performance é inferior a TPH.**

### TPC (Table per Concrete class)

Cada classe concreta (que pode ser instanciada na hierarquia de classes) é mapeada para uma tabela específica, contemplando os campos da classe abstrada.

Como você pode observar, não é só uma questão de performance, mas a decisão por um ou outro *pattern* vai depender também da sua modelagem.

Para testar, recomendo montar sua hierarquia de classes e usar um Stopwatch ao fazer acesso aos dados como o @Luís Deschamps Rudge sugeriu na resposta dele e usar o [Entity Framework Profile](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) para ver o que está acontecendo "nos bastidores" no banco de dados e assim tomar a decisão conforme sua necessidade.

Answer (score -1):

Usa o Analyze do Visual Studio, com ele você vai conseguir saber aonde esta levando mais tempo em sua aplicação, ja resolvemos alguns problemas de desempenho usando isso.

Você vai em Analyze no Menu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

depois sua aplicação vai entrar em debug para iniciar a coleta das informações, ai neste instantes execute os testes que deseja, enquanto ele coleta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto terminar você vai em Stop Profile.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aguarde, que sua aplicação vai sair do debug e será gerado o resultado, ai é só analisar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]